# Is there a particular way to get the mouse position with Ionic and Vue?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, ionic-framework, mouseevent

I am looking to get the mouse X position in pixel (Ionic 6/Vue/Typescript) in order to resize a sidebar menu.

I try the code on the documentation : https://ionicframework.com/docs/utilities/gestures but it's not working.

On my function `onMove` , I have an error: `Missing return type on function`.

```
<template>
  <ion-page>
    <ion-split-pane
      content-id="main"
    >
      <ion-menu
        content-id="main"
        class="sidebar"
      >
        <ion-content class="ion-padding ">
          // my content
        </ion-content>

        <div class="rectangle"></div>
        <p>
          Swipe to start tracking
        </p>

        <!-- in order to resize the menu -->
        <div class="sidebar__side"></div>
      </ion-menu>

      <ion-router-outlet id="main" />
    </ion-split-pane>
  </ion-page>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue';
import { createGesture } from '@ionic/core';

// get mouse x position in pixel while clicking
const pRef = ref();
const rectangleRef = ref();
const gesture = createGesture({
  el: rectangleRef.value,
  onMove: (detail) => { onMove(detail); }
})

gesture.enable();

function onMove(detail) {
  const type = detail.type;
  const currentX = detail.currentX;
  const deltaX = detail.deltaX;

  return pRef.value.innerHTML = `
    <div>Type: ${type}</div>
    <div>Current X: ${currentX}</div>
    <div>Delta X: ${deltaX}</div>`
}


</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>

.rectangle {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
}

.split-pane-visible {
  --side-min-width: 200px;
  --side-max-width: 800px;
  --side-width: 300px;
  overflow: visible;
}

</style>
```